# Image not showing properly in Grid

Tags: html, model-view-controller, grid

I am trying to show images in my Grid where I added if else part. In this grid else part is working properly but in If part where i am  using static image is not showing. Can you please let me know where i am doing mistake?

```
 @Html.Grid(Model).Named("ServiceCompendiumData").Columns(x =>
   {
         x.Add(y => y.Physician_ImageFileName).Titled("Photo").Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).Filterable(false).RenderValueAs(y => @<div style="width:100px;">
                @if (y.Physician_ImageBase64String == null)
                         {
                           <img src='~/Images/_defaultMan.png' alt="Image" style="height:100px; width:100px;"/>
                         }
                         else
                         {<img alt="Image" style="height:100px; width:100px;" src='@y.Physician_ImageBase64String' ) />}
            </div>).SetWidth(150);
       x.Add().Encoded(false)
                   .Sanitized(false)
                   .SetWidth(20)
                   .RenderValueAs(y => Html.ActionLink(" Edit", "PhysicianBiodata", new { Id = y.ID }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary fa fa-chevron-circle-down" }));

       x.Add().Encoded(false)
           .Sanitized(false)
           .SetWidth(20)
           .RenderValueAs(y => Html.ActionLink(" Delete", "Delete", new { ClinicIdToDelete = y.ID }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary fa fa-chevron-circle-down", @onclick = "return DeleteConfirm(" + y.ID + ");" }));

   }).Sortable(true).WithPaging(10).WithMultipleFilters();
```

Answer (score 0):

changed the condition of If(string.IsNullOrEmpty(y.Physician_ImageBase64String)). then it worked